SwiftUI List subview performance issue on macOS
When using SwiftUI ‘List’ with a large number of elements (4000+), I noticed a significant performance issue if extracting the views inside the ‘ForEach’ block into their own subview class. It affects scrolling performance, and using the scroll handle in the scrollbar causes stutters and beachballs. This seems to happen on macOS only ... the same project works fine on iOS.
Here's what I mean:
struct PlainListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
            fetchRequest: Item.myFetchRequest(),
            animation: nil)
    
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>
    @State private var multiSelectedContacts = Set<Item.ID>()
    @State var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List (selection: $multiSelectedContacts) {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    
                    // 1. this subview is the problem ... replace it with the contents of the subview, and it works fine
                    
                    PlainContentItemView(item: item)

                    // 2. Uncomment this part for it to work fine (and comment out PlainContentItemView above)
                    /*
                     HStack {
                        if let timestamp = item.timestamp, let itemNumber = item.itemNumber {
                            Text("\(itemNumber) - \(timestamp, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                        }
                    }*/
                }
            }
            
            Text("Count: \(items.count)")
            
            .toolbar {
                
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
        // just to add 4000 records to Core Data

        let fetchRequest = Item.fetchRequest()
        let count = try? viewContext.count(for: fetchRequest)
        
        withAnimation {
            for i in 0...3999 {
                let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
                newItem.timestamp = Date()
                newItem.itemNumber = "\(((count ?? 0) + 1 + i))"
            }
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PlainContentItemView: View {
    
    let item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        
        if let timestamp = item.timestamp, let itemNumber = item.itemNumber {
            HStack {
                Text("\(itemNumber) - \(timestamp, formatter: itemFormatter)")
            }
        }
    }
}

private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .long
    return formatter
}()


extension Item {
    static func myFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Item> {
        let fr = Self.fetchRequest()
        fr.includesPropertyValues = false
        fr.fetchBatchSize = 100
        //fr.fetchLimit = 50
        fr.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)]
        return fr
    }
}

extension Item : Identifiable {
    public var id: String {
        return self.objectID.uriRepresentation().absoluteString
    }
}

Item is a NSManagedObject subclass, and conforms to Identifiable by using the objectID string value.
With this, scrolling up and down using the scrolling handle, causes stuttering scrolling and can beachball on my machine (MacBook Pro M1). I also notice a lot of hangs in Instruments.
If I comment out the ‘PlainContentItemView’ and just use the HStack directly (which is what was extracted to ‘PlainContentItemView’), the performance noticeably improves, and I can scroll up and down smoothly.
I've also found that if the List isn't loaded from Core Data, but from in-memory objects, it works fine.
This is what I mean:
struct ListItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

// works fine when not loading from core data
struct PlainNonCoreDataContentView: View {
    let items = Array(1...10000).map { ListItem(name: "Item \($0)") }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(items) { item in
                ExtractedView(item: item)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Large List")
            
            Text("Count: \(items.count)")
        }
    }
}

struct ExtractedView: View {
    let item: ListItem
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.name)
    }
}

So it's some combination of using Core Data NSManagedObjects and extracting subviews (and macOS) that is causing this performance issue.
Any ideas on what might be causing this, and how to improve performance here? I've tried tweaking the fetch request here in different ways, but nothing improves it (other than removing the subview and writing everything inline, which isn't feasible for my large project).
